# Django TypeError: id() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

Tags: python, mysql, django

So I have been trying to implement a way to upload multiple images to a post. The way I did it is to have tables. One for the actual post, and one of the multiple images uploaded. I was planning to link them with a foreign key but it is not working. My terminal started throwing the error "TypeError: id() takes exactly one argument (0 given)" . It throws me this error whenever I migrate it.

I am not sure how to fix this.

MY code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
from django.conf import settings

from PIL import Image

import os

DEFAULT_IMAGE_ID = 1

# Create your models here.
class Projects(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    files = models.FileField(upload_to='files/', blank=True)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', height_field = 'img_height', width_field = 'img_width',blank=True)
    img_height = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=600)
    img_width = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=300)
    #feature_images = models.ForeignKey(P_Images, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=DEFAULT_IMAGE_ID)
    feature_images = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Generates a random string 
        unique_string = get_random_string(length=32)

        # Combines title and unique string to slugify
        slugtext = self.title + "-" + "unique_id=-" + unique_string
        self.slug = slugify(slugtext)

        return super(Projects, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class P_Images(models.Model):
    p_file = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=None)
    p_uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    #fk_post = models
    fk_post = models.ForeignKey(Projects, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The errorlog

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, projects, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying projects.0005_auto_20180823_0553...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 122, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 216, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 525, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 630, in _alter_field
    new_default = self.effective_default(new_field)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 218, in effective_default
    default = field.get_default()
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 775, in get_default
    return self._get_default()
TypeError: id() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

I use a MySQL database for this. This error started popping up after I updated my tables to be able to link with each other. I plan the fk_post of the P_Images to contain the feature_image value of Projects for the foreign key.

005_migration.py

```
import builtins
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('projects', '0004_auto_20180823_0547'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='p_images',
            name='fk_post',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='projects.Projects'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='projects',
            name='feature_images',
            field=models.IntegerField(default=builtins.id),
        ),
    ]
```

please let me know if the migration.py tells you something or nothing.

Comment: It your get_p_image_filename you have a typo in your strut formatting - you have slug_slug and not slug_title... could be this!

Comment: The error is not in the code you have posted, but in the migration.

Comment: @DanielRoseman How do I fix this if it is in migration?

Comment: I don't know, you'll need to post 0005_auto_20180823_0553.py.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I just posted it in my post. Please let me know if that is correct or if I need something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have something very bizarre in your migration:

```
models.IntegerField(default=builtins.id)
```

This is referring to the builtin `id` function, which requires an argument because it returns the internal ID of an object in Python. It has nothing to do with database IDs, and doesn't belong here at all. I can only guess that you were asked for a default when creating the migration and you just typed in `id`.

You should delete that default from the migration, but that may make it unable to execute. You could also try a default of `0`, which makes sense there; but your actual models code shows that field as the primary key, so you presumably have another subsequent migration that changes the field again; and 0 wouldn't work as a pk.

If you're still in development and don't have any data you need to keep, I would suggest deleting your database and migrations completely and starting again with makemigrations.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will definitely do this

Comment: life saver! I had the same issue when I entered in a default value incorrectly. I had forgotten to make the value (`>>> "all" `) a string, and instead typed (`>>> all`)

Answer (score -1):

I think this error occurred because you haven't set a default value to your foreign key. For your previous P_Images instances (before your current migration), they don't have a Projects id related to them. 
The error text shown also confirms it:

```
return self._get_default()
TypeError: id() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

So try adding a default value :

```
DEFAULT_PROJECT = 1 # or the id of any project that does exist
fk_post = models.ForeignKey(Projects, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default = DEFAULT_PROJECT)
```

Comment: This is still not working :( I got 4 migrations now that are not migrated lol